# LinearLayout over ListView with CardView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cardview

I have simple List View and Card View, then I'm using Adapter to create list while list items are those cards which are in Linear Layout. Actually list scrolls but once touching on card it does not.

Here is an example  :

[image]

well, if Itouch there on the sides it will scroll, otherwise it does not... how to fix this problem?

Edit: here`s code

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ListAdapter LAdapter= new SimpleAdapter(
ActivityMain.this, jsonList, R.layout.list_items, new String[]{sTITLE, sUSER}, new int[]{R.id.title_dayo, R.id.user_dayo}); myList.setAdapter(LAdapter);
```

and here`s layouts
[image]

Comment: can you post the code for your adapter and implementation please?

Comment: Here`s it, i uploaded adapter an layouts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, well problem was actually another thing and this code and this layout actually worked. problem was that i used another RecycleView over ListView